# Different symbol for g

Tags: symbols

How can I write in "curly" form of g [image]
in an equation?

Just "g" gives me this  [image]

Comment: You need a different math font, for example, `\usepackage{mathptmx}`

Comment: Well, it's up to you, but please don't try to differentiate between closed ("curly" g) and open g. If you just like the look of the closed g more then it's your document, but do please bear in mind that it has no difference in meaning, and whether the change in font I think you'll need is worth it for a different g symbol is something you should carefully consider. Remember that maths uses italics and the point of the italic shape is to resemble a slanted style of handwriting (italic). very few people use a closed g in handwriting although many italic fonts do feature a closed g

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Comment: @Au101 can't agree more with you --- there are documents (some electronic application note, for example) that differentiate symbols just with the shape of the gliph... practically impossible to read "aloud in your head".

Comment: the computer modern slanted font has a closed "g", with the same slope as the italic, so with a bit of effort, that might be substituted.  but as already advised, don't use both in the same document with different meanings.

Comment: i that the roman font "g" ? in that case it would be `\mathrm{g}`

Comment: The two forms of g are not equivalent in all contexts: for IPA, only one form is valid. And with generic tagging like "\mathrm{}", you don't known which form you'll get unless you use specific a package with specific fonts, or unless you use the specific Unicode code point for the letter form required by IPA, and your TeX engine supports an Unicode encoding on input.

Answer (score 9):

As noted in the comments the standard slanted font has a `g` of this form.  You can use it as `\textsl{g}`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}

\( g_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} \) vs. \( \textsl{g}_{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} \)

\end{document}
```

The package `amstext` is automatically loaded if you use `amsmath` or `mathtools`.  In the above example the package is not needed, but without it you will not get good results if you use the symbol as a superscript or subscript.

Another caveat is that in the above code the symbol `\textsl{g}` will change with the surrounding text, for example `\textbf{A bold sentence containing $\textsl{g}$` will have the symbol bold.  That may or may not be what you want.  If you need the symbol to be exactly the same regardless define a macro

```
\newcommand{\cg}{\textnormal{\textsl{g}}}
```

and use `\cg` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I like to add my answer. Looking the image I think that with the combination of `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` it is possible to have the similar output that it is request of the user.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[g_{\alpha\beta,\gamma}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]